# rails 3.2 haml email template link_to error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml, email-templates

I have an application (rails 3.2) with haml (3.1.4) emails. In the email template I wanted to use link_to, but apparently none of those 4 is working in production:

```
#{link_to(my_models_url)}
= link_to(my_models_url)

/ @url set to my_models_url
#{link_to(@url)}
= link_to(@url)
```

On development mode everything works fine, but in production, I keep getting the following error:

```
No route matches {}
 actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:503:in `raise_routing_error'
```

It works when I use helper methods before:

```
/ @my_link set to link_to(my_models_url)
#{@my_link}
= @my_link
```

But this is not convenient, if there are more links in the email and in general I don't see why any of the first 4 options should not be ok. I have no idea where is this problem comming from. I would appreciate any help on this...

SOLUTION:

Thanks to iWasRobbed I found where my problems were:

1. all {resource}_path and {resource}_url have to be set in mailers as @variables, they are not available in mailer views
2. apparently link_to() method in mailer is not the same as in rails views... it always needs 2 arguments, so instead of link_to(@link) available in views, one needs to do link_to(@link,@link). Pffff...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the URL within the `mailer.rb` file.  This isn't a HAML issue so much as it's just the way ActionMailer was designed.

```
def some_mailer_here
  @url = my_models_url
end
```

Then in your mailer view you can do:

```
= link_to("My models URL", @url)
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#generating-urls-in-action-mailer-views

Comment: Thanks for an answer. I solved my problem in production, but I still have a question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9039970/helper-methods-available-in-mailer-views-depend-on-environment . Do you possibly know the answer to this one too?